# Cache Page Load and Delete after 30 Minutes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, fadein, browser-cache

I'm using a fade-in effect on my homepage, but as suggested, I should cache the page load so that I only trigger the effect once. I'm not too savvy with javascript, but this is what I have. Suggestions?

Again, once the page is cached, I plan to disable the fade effect, so that it's not nagging the user every time the page is loaded.

**UPDATE:** If I know that my average visit time is around 10 minutes, how can I delete this visit from the cache after 30 minutes, so that the next visit, the page fades in again? Is this called "time to live?"

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (window.localStorage && !localStorage['faded']) {
            localStorage['faded'] = true;
            $('body').hide().fadeIn(500);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `localStorage`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        if (window.localStorage && !localStorage['faded']) {
            localStorage['faded'] = true;
            $('body').hide().fadeIn(500);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Browsers that don't support `localStorage` are probably going to choke on the fade in effect anyways, so they won't miss it.

Comment: `sessionStorage` might be better, depending how often the page gets updated.

Comment: @kurzweilguy: Well, that entire `else` block is the problem. Replace the contents of the `$(window).load` callback with my code.

Comment: @kurzweilguy: It's `window.localStorage`, not `document.localStorage`.

Comment: @kurzweilguy: I'd rather not.